# Select most recent "custom object" for a batch of ID

Tags: master-detail

I have a custom object which have a Master relationship towards the Account object and a custom DateTime field.

I'd like to select, for each Account, only the custom"Custom Object" with highest Datetime. Is it possible?

Comment: Are you trying to add a rollup? You can do `MAX` with Datetime fields.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` clauses in a [`Left Outer Join`](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com#Left_Outer_Join):

```
SELECT (SELECT Id FROM CustomChildren__r ORDER BY CustomDatetime__c DESC LIMIT 1)
FROM Account
```

---

Here is a more concrete example which should be analogous and can be run in any org. You can get the `Name` of the most recently created `User` assigned to each `Profile` with a very similar join:

```
SELECT Name, (SELECT Name FROM Users ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1)
FROM Profile
```